# Rendering a widget on top of another component?

Tags: reactjs, react-widgets

I want to render a react-chat-widget positioned over a google-map. When I do this the widget container (minimized space until clicked) is preventing me from being able to interact with part of the map. How do I overlap components so that only the 'active' component is functional?

Answer (score 0):

You can fix this by CSS. Change the component CSS position: absolute. If required use z-index to make the component visible. I believe the problem is the overlapping component is occupying the entire widget space rendering the other one unclickable.